# TV used as secondary monitor through wireless display stooped working

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, multiple-monitors, tv

I received today my new television, a Toshiba 50U6863DB. I was able to set it up and connect it to my home Wi-Fi. It worked properly, including using it to stream YouTube and Netflix. I was able as well to connect it to my PC (Windows 10) through wireless display (Right click on desktop, Display setting, Connect to a wireless display and found and clicked on the TV that appeared on the list on the right) and I used it for a little while as a secondary monitor that mirrored my primary one.

Unfortunately the TV screen, while mirroring my PC, was flickering and I started to fiddle with it to solve the issue; while doing so I attempted to change the monitor resolution from 1920 x 1200 (I think), the default, to that of my primary monitor that is 1920 x 1080.  The TV and the PC screen both went black.

After I restarted both the PC and the TV, Windows was again able to detect the TV but was not able to connect it any longer (when I try, the TV screen and PC monitor go black for a couple of seconds and after, they go back to normal and the PC says connection failed). After fiddling around more, I gave up and I reset the TV to factory setting, but not even that sorted the issue.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try a software update. See this [post](https://forum.toshiba.eu/showthread.php?99082-50U6863DB-Netflix-freezes-and-crashes-Tv&s=99a2164d9b01a0c81817f815176b5ac4&p=352170&viewfull=1#post352170) and if it doesn't help the posting below that.

(EDIT: added the relevant parts in case the linked posts get deleted/are not accessible)

1. (software upgrade)

> When tv is on press home button - settings - system - more - then click OK on software upgrade - scan for upgrade

2. (workaround)

> I've had this happen even with the latest firmware update, but I did find a way around it, disable the Internet connection in the setting launch Netflix then it will say network connection error etc... Click more detail then select close Netflix. This will kill the process when you relaunch it with Internet connection it will work again but it's a work around it may countiue to happen, Toshiba need to sort of the firmware :/ not sure on the exact specs of the TV yet but maybe the system is underpowered and Netflix locks it up, once I have got stuck in Netflix the only way I could exit was to turn off the TV. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved by Toshiba customer service. I post it here for future reference.

Resetting the TV to factory setting proved useless and no luck with updating my drivers or software update (Thanks anyway Freddy). After several attempts, we realize that different computers were indeed able to connect with the TV and therefore the problem was not on the TV but on the PC. The technician guess was that my computer was outputting in a resolution that the TV was not able to decipher and therefore no connection between the two was possible and, because no connection was possible, I could not access the options menu to change the resolution output for the secondary screen in my PC. After uninstalling and reinstalling the graphic card drivers (that did not help) the advice was to format the PC. That solved the issue.

I'm sure that there are a better way to solve this particular problem but if you have no other alternative that works.